# JVM crash in lucene - org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput - klass: 'org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput'

Tags: lucene, crash, jvm

When indexing around 100 records, my application has the following exception - JVM crash in lucene.

The options passed to the JAVA VM are:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -server -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=1800000  -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=1800000 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

I am using jdk1.6.0_45 and lucene-3.6.2.

The link on Red Hat website has the similar issues, but a subscription is required to access that knowledge.

Red Hat Link : https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/450653

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f6e21041590, pid=29567, tid=140106205816576
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f6dac184800):  JavaThread "HTTP-209" [_thread_in_Java, id=4418, stack(0x00007f6d0490e000,0x00007f6d04a0f000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x00007f6d374260b5

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f6d374261f7, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000142, RDX=0xffffffffffffffdc
RSP=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0, RBP=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0, RSI=0x00000000bd2261a0, RDI=0x00007f6d374261ed
R8 =0x00000000000020b5, R9 =0x00000000bd226058, R10=0x00007f6e21041cc0, R11=0x00000000bd226468
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000bd2264c8, R14=0x00007f6d374261f7, R15=0x00007f6dac184800
RIP=0x00007f6e21041590, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010282, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0)
0x00007f6d04a0b2d0:   0000000000000152 00007f6e2134d4af
0x00007f6d04a0b2e0:   00000000bd226468 0000014200000000
0x00007f6d04a0b2f0:   00000000bd226058 00007f6e000020b5
0x00007f6d04a0b300:   00000000e7a94378 0000000000000001
0x00007f6d04a0b310:   00007f6d04a0b330 00007f6e29e288e8
0x00007f6d04a0b320:   00000000000028ed 00007f6d04a0b3f0
0x00007f6d04a0b330:   00007f6d04a0b780 00007f6e29b1a6ac
0x00007f6d04a0b340:   00007f6d04a0b3c0 00007f6e21005a82
0x00007f6d04a0b350:   00007f6d04a0b730 00007f6e21005a82
0x00007f6d04a0b360:   0000000000000142 0000000000000000
0x00007f6d04a0b370:   00000000bd226058 00000000bd226468
0x00007f6d04a0b380:   00007f6d04a0b380 00000000a61c0dd4
0x00007f6d04a0b390:   00007f6d04a0b3f0 00000000a62a7230
0x00007f6d04a0b3a0:   00000000a7826388 00000000a61c0e20
0x00007f6d04a0b3b0:   00007f6d04a0b360 00007f6d04a0b3d0
0x00007f6d04a0b3c0:   00007f6d04a0b438 00007f6e21005a82
0x00007f6d04a0b3d0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000142
0x00007f6d04a0b3e0:   0000000000000000 00000000bd226058
0x00007f6d04a0b3f0:   00000000bd226468 00007f6d04a0b3f8
0x00007f6d04a0b400:   00000000a62b80ff 00007f6d04a0b470
0x00007f6d04a0b410:   00000000a62bca58 00000000a78184a8
0x00007f6d04a0b420:   00000000a62b8150 00007f6d04a0b3d0
0x00007f6d04a0b430:   00007f6d04a0b480 000000000000108e
0x00007f6d04a0b440:   00007f6e21be5e70 000000000000108e
0x00007f6d04a0b450:   0000000000000000 00007f6d00000142
0x00007f6d04a0b460:   00007f6d00000000 00000000bd226058
0x00007f6d04a0b470:   00000000bd226018 00007f6e21be5e70
0x00007f6d04a0b480:   00000000bd226018 0000000000000142
0x00007f6d04a0b490:   00007f6d04a0b4b0 0000000000000005
0x00007f6d04a0b4a0:   0000000000000001 00007f6e214c6e12
0x00007f6d04a0b4b0:   00000000bd226018 00007f6e214d31d4
0x00007f6d04a0b4c0:   00007f6ea62bb538 00007f6e29d4e872 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f6e21041590)
0x00007f6e21041570:   46 08 48 83 c7 02 48 83 c6 02 f7 c1 01 00 00 00
0x00007f6e21041580:   74 06 8a 47 08 88 46 08 48 33 c0 c9 c3 66 66 90
0x00007f6e21041590:   48 8b 44 d7 e8 48 89 44 d6 e8 48 8b 44 d7 f0 48
0x00007f6e210415a0:   89 44 d6 f0 48 8b 44 d7 f8 48 89 44 d6 f8 48 8b 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f6d374261f7 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000142 is an unknown value
RDX=0xffffffffffffffdc is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f6dac184800
RBP=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f6dac184800
RSI=0x00000000bd2261a0 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 1024
RDI=0x00007f6d374261ed is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000000020b5 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000bd226058 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 1024
R10=StubRoutines::unsafe_arraycopy [0x00007f6e21041cc0, 0x00007f6e21041cfb[ (59 bytes)R11=0x00000000bd226468 is an oop
org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput 
 - klass: 'org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput'
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000bd2264c8 is an oop
java.nio.DirectByteBufferR 
 - klass: 'java/nio/DirectByteBufferR'
R14=0x00007f6d374261f7 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f6dac184800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f6d0490e000,0x00007f6d04a0f000],  sp=0x00007f6d04a0b2d0,  free space=1012k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
v  ~StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f6d6c14d000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1018, stack(0x00007f6d010e9000,0x00007f6d011ea000)]
  0x00007f6d6c089800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=15174, stack(0x00007f6d013ec000,0x00007f6d014ed000)]
  0x00007f6d740cf800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=15167, stack(0x00007f6d014ed000,0x00007f6d015ee000)]
  0x00007f6d741c7800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=15020, stack(0x00007f6d012eb000,0x00007f6d013ec000)]
  0x00007f6d741ba800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=14938, stack(0x00007f6d01af3000,0x00007f6d01bf4000)]
  0x00007f6d700d9000 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=14837, stack(0x00007f6d018f1000,0x00007f6d019f2000)]
  0x00007f6d6407a000 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=14736, stack(0x00007f6d016ef000,0x00007f6d017f0000)]
  0x00007f6d4c0d7800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=14535, stack(0x00007f6d015ee000,0x00007f6d016ef000)]
  0x00007f6d6c088800 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=14414, stack(0x00007f6d019f2000,0x00007f6d01af3000)]
  0x00007f6d6c099000 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=14293, stack(0x00007f6d017f0000,0x00007f6d018f1000)]
  0x00007f6d6c087000 JavaThread "pool-14-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=14069, stack(0x00007f6d01ee4000,0x00007f6d01fe5000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c9800 JavaThread "HTTP-250" [_thread_blocked, id=6289, stack(0x00007f6d01fe5000,0x00007f6d020e6000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c8000 JavaThread "HTTP-249" [_thread_blocked, id=6181, stack(0x00007f6d020e6000,0x00007f6d021e7000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c6800 JavaThread "HTTP-248" [_thread_blocked, id=6180, stack(0x00007f6d021e7000,0x00007f6d022e8000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c5000 JavaThread "HTTP-247" [_thread_blocked, id=6099, stack(0x00007f6d022e8000,0x00007f6d023e9000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c3800 JavaThread "HTTP-246" [_thread_blocked, id=6098, stack(0x00007f6d023e9000,0x00007f6d024ea000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c2000 JavaThread "HTTP-245" [_thread_blocked, id=6097, stack(0x00007f6d024ea000,0x00007f6d025eb000)]
  0x00007f6dac1c0800 JavaThread "HTTP-244" [_thread_blocked, id=5982, stack(0x00007f6d025eb000,0x00007f6d026ec000)]
  0x00007f6dac1bf000 JavaThread "HTTP-243" [_thread_blocked, id=5596, stack(0x00007f6d026ec000,0x00007f6d027ed000)]
  0x00007f6dac1bd000 JavaThread "HTTP-242" [_thread_blocked, id=5497, stack(0x00007f6d027ed000,0x00007f6d028ee000)]
  0x00007f6dac1bb000 JavaThread "HTTP-241" [_thread_blocked, id=5496, stack(0x00007f6d028ee000,0x00007f6d029ef000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b8800 JavaThread "HTTP-240" [_thread_blocked, id=5495, stack(0x00007f6d029ef000,0x00007f6d02af0000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b6800 JavaThread "HTTP-239" [_thread_blocked, id=5385, stack(0x00007f6d02af0000,0x00007f6d02bf1000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b5000 JavaThread "HTTP-238" [_thread_blocked, id=5384, stack(0x00007f6d02bf1000,0x00007f6d02cf2000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b3800 JavaThread "HTTP-237" [_thread_blocked, id=5383, stack(0x00007f6d02cf2000,0x00007f6d02df3000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b2000 JavaThread "HTTP-236" [_thread_blocked, id=5357, stack(0x00007f6d02df3000,0x00007f6d02ef4000)]
  0x00007f6dac1b0800 JavaThread "HTTP-235" [_thread_blocked, id=5356, stack(0x00007f6d02ef4000,0x00007f6d02ff5000)]
  0x00007f6dac1af000 JavaThread "HTTP-234" [_thread_blocked, id=5127, stack(0x00007f6d02ff5000,0x00007f6d030f6000)]
  0x00007f6dac1ad800 JavaThread "HTTP-233" [_thread_blocked, id=5126, stack(0x00007f6d030f6000,0x00007f6d031f7000)]
  0x00007f6dac1ac000 JavaThread "HTTP-232" [_thread_blocked, id=5125, stack(0x00007f6d031f7000,0x00007f6d032f8000)]
  0x00007f6dac1aa800 JavaThread "HTTP-231" [_thread_blocked, id=5124, stack(0x00007f6d032f8000,0x00007f6d033f9000)]
  0x00007f6dac1a8800 JavaThread "HTTP-230" [_thread_blocked, id=5123, stack(0x00007f6d033f9000,0x00007f6d034fa000)]
  0x00007f6dac1a6800 JavaThread "HTTP-229" [_thread_blocked, id=5122, stack(0x00007f6d034fa000,0x00007f6d035fb000)]
  0x00007f6dac1a4800 JavaThread "HTTP-228" [_thread_blocked, id=5121, stack(0x00007f6d035fb000,0x00007f6d036fc000)]
  0x00007f6dac1a2800 JavaThread "HTTP-227" [_thread_blocked, id=5120, stack(0x00007f6d036fc000,0x00007f6d037fd000)]
  0x00007f6dac1a0800 JavaThread "HTTP-226" [_thread_blocked, id=5119, stack(0x00007f6d037fd000,0x00007f6d038fe000)]
  0x00007f6dac19e800 JavaThread "HTTP-225" [_thread_blocked, id=5118, stack(0x00007f6d038fe000,0x00007f6d039ff000)]
  0x00007f6dac19d000 JavaThread "HTTP-224" [_thread_blocked, id=5117, stack(0x00007f6d039ff000,0x00007f6d03b00000)]
  0x00007f6dac19b800 JavaThread "HTTP-223" [_thread_blocked, id=5116, stack(0x00007f6d03b00000,0x00007f6d03c01000)]
  0x00007f6dac19a000 JavaThread "HTTP-222" [_thread_blocked, id=4977, stack(0x00007f6d03c01000,0x00007f6d03d02000)]
  0x00007f6dac198800 JavaThread "HTTP-221" [_thread_blocked, id=4976, stack(0x00007f6d03d02000,0x00007f6d03e03000)]
  0x00007f6dac197000 JavaThread "HTTP-220" [_thread_blocked, id=4818, stack(0x00007f6d03e03000,0x00007f6d03f04000)]
  0x00007f6dac195000 JavaThread "HTTP-219" [_thread_blocked, id=4817, stack(0x00007f6d03f04000,0x00007f6d04005000)]
  0x00007f6dac193000 JavaThread "HTTP-218" [_thread_blocked, id=4648, stack(0x00007f6d04005000,0x00007f6d04106000)]
  0x00007f6dac191800 JavaThread "HTTP-217" [_thread_blocked, id=4647, stack(0x00007f6d04106000,0x00007f6d04207000)]
  0x00007f6dac190000 JavaThread "HTTP-216" [_thread_blocked, id=4646, stack(0x00007f6d04207000,0x00007f6d04308000)]
  0x00007f6dac18e000 JavaThread "HTTP-215" [_thread_blocked, id=4645, stack(0x00007f6d04308000,0x00007f6d04409000)]
  0x00007f6dac18c800 JavaThread "HTTP-214" [_thread_blocked, id=4563, stack(0x00007f6d04409000,0x00007f6d0450a000)]
  0x00007f6dac18b000 JavaThread "HTTP-213" [_thread_blocked, id=4562, stack(0x00007f6d0450a000,0x00007f6d0460b000)]
  0x00007f6dac189800 JavaThread "HTTP-212" [_thread_blocked, id=4561, stack(0x00007f6d0460b000,0x00007f6d0470c000)]
  0x00007f6dac188000 JavaThread "HTTP-211" [_thread_blocked, id=4454, stack(0x00007f6d0470c000,0x00007f6d0480d000)]
  0x00007f6dac186000 JavaThread "HTTP-210" [_thread_blocked, id=4453, stack(0x00007f6d0480d000,0x00007f6d0490e000)]
=>0x00007f6dac184800 JavaThread "HTTP-209" [_thread_in_Java, id=4418, stack(0x00007f6d0490e000,0x00007f6d04a0f000)]
  0x00007f6dac183000 JavaThread "HTTP-208" [_thread_blocked, id=4417, stack(0x00007f6d04a0f000,0x00007f6d04b10000)]
  0x00007f6dac181800 JavaThread "HTTP-207" [_thread_blocked, id=4416, stack(0x00007f6d04b10000,0x00007f6d04c11000)]
  0x00007f6dac180000 JavaThread "HTTP-206" [_thread_blocked, id=4155, stack(0x00007f6d04c11000,0x00007f6d04d12000)]
  0x00007f6dac17e800 JavaThread "HTTP-205" [_thread_blocked, id=4154, stack(0x00007f6d04d12000,0x00007f6d04e13000)]
  0x00007f6dac17d000 JavaThread "HTTP-204" [_thread_blocked, id=3984, stack(0x00007f6d04e13000,0x00007f6d04f14000)]
  0x00007f6dac17b000 JavaThread "HTTP-203" [_thread_blocked, id=3983, stack(0x00007f6d04f14000,0x00007f6d05015000)]
  0x00007f6dac179800 JavaThread "HTTP-202" [_thread_blocked, id=3982, stack(0x00007f6d05015000,0x00007f6d05116000)]
  0x00007f6dac178000 JavaThread "HTTP-201" [_thread_blocked, id=3890, stack(0x00007f6d05116000,0x00007f6d05217000)]
  0x00007f6dac176800 JavaThread "HTTP-200" [_thread_blocked, id=3889, stack(0x00007f6d05217000,0x00007f6d05318000)]
  0x00007f6dac174800 JavaThread "HTTP-199" [_thread_blocked, id=3801, stack(0x00007f6d05318000,0x00007f6d05419000)]
  0x00007f6dac173000 JavaThread "HTTP-198" [_thread_blocked, id=3800, stack(0x00007f6d05419000,0x00007f6d0551a000)]
  0x00007f6dac171800 JavaThread "HTTP-197" [_thread_blocked, id=3777, stack(0x00007f6d0551a000,0x00007f6d0561b000)]
  0x00007f6dac170000 JavaThread "HTTP-196" [_thread_blocked, id=3515, stack(0x00007f6d0561b000,0x00007f6d0571c000)]
  0x00007f6dac16e800 JavaThread "HTTP-195" [_thread_blocked, id=3494, stack(0x00007f6d0571c000,0x00007f6d0581d000)]
  0x00007f6dac16d000 JavaThread "HTTP-194" [_thread_blocked, id=3493, stack(0x00007f6d0581d000,0x00007f6d0591e000)]
  0x00007f6dac16b800 JavaThread "HTTP-193" [_thread_blocked, id=3492, stack(0x00007f6d0591e000,0x00007f6d05a1f000)]
  0x00007f6dac16a000 JavaThread "HTTP-192" [_thread_blocked, id=3417, stack(0x00007f6d05a1f000,0x00007f6d05b20000)]
  0x00007f6dac168800 JavaThread "HTTP-191" [_thread_blocked, id=3416, stack(0x00007f6d05b20000,0x00007f6d05c21000)]
  0x00007f6dac167000 JavaThread "HTTP-190" [_thread_blocked, id=3323, stack(0x00007f6d05c21000,0x00007f6d05d22000)]
  0x00007f6dac165800 JavaThread "HTTP-189" [_thread_blocked, id=3322, stack(0x00007f6d05d22000,0x00007f6d05e23000)]
  0x00007f6dac164000 JavaThread "HTTP-188" [_thread_blocked, id=3321, stack(0x00007f6d05e23000,0x00007f6d05f24000)]
  0x00007f6dac162800 JavaThread "HTTP-187" [_thread_blocked, id=3209, stack(0x00007f6d05f24000,0x00007f6d06025000)]
  0x00007f6dac160800 JavaThread "HTTP-186" [_thread_blocked, id=3095, stack(0x00007f6d06025000,0x00007f6d06126000)]
  0x00007f6dac15f000 JavaThread "HTTP-185" [_thread_blocked, id=3094, stack(0x00007f6d06126000,0x00007f6d06227000)]
  0x00007f6dac15d800 JavaThread "HTTP-184" [_thread_blocked, id=2060, stack(0x00007f6d06227000,0x00007f6d06328000)]
  0x00007f6dac15b800 JavaThread "HTTP-183" [_thread_blocked, id=2055, stack(0x00007f6d06328000,0x00007f6d06429000)]
  0x00007f6dac15a000 JavaThread "HTTP-182" [_thread_blocked, id=2052, stack(0x00007f6d06429000,0x00007f6d0652a000)]
  0x00007f6dac158800 JavaThread "HTTP-181" [_thread_blocked, id=2044, stack(0x00007f6d0652a000,0x00007f6d0662b000)]
  0x00007f6dac157000 JavaThread "HTTP-180" [_thread_blocked, id=2043, stack(0x00007f6d0662b000,0x00007f6d0672c000)]
  0x00007f6dac155800 JavaThread "HTTP-179" [_thread_blocked, id=2042, stack(0x00007f6d0672c000,0x00007f6d0682d000)]
  0x00007f6dac153800 JavaThread "HTTP-178" [_thread_blocked, id=2023, stack(0x00007f6d0682d000,0x00007f6d0692e000)]
  0x00007f6dac151800 JavaThread "HTTP-177" [_thread_blocked, id=2022, stack(0x00007f6d0692e000,0x00007f6d06a2f000)]
  0x00007f6dac14f800 JavaThread "HTTP-176" [_thread_blocked, id=2021, stack(0x00007f6d06a2f000,0x00007f6d06b30000)]
  0x00007f6dac14e000 JavaThread "HTTP-175" [_thread_blocked, id=2020, stack(0x00007f6d06b30000,0x00007f6d06c31000)]
  0x00007f6dac14c800 JavaThread "HTTP-174" [_thread_blocked, id=2017, stack(0x00007f6d06c31000,0x00007f6d06d32000)]
  0x00007f6dac14b000 JavaThread "HTTP-173" [_thread_blocked, id=2016, stack(0x00007f6d06d32000,0x00007f6d06e33000)]
  0x00007f6dac149800 JavaThread "HTTP-172" [_thread_blocked, id=2012, stack(0x00007f6d06e33000,0x00007f6d06f34000)]
  0x00007f6dac148000 JavaThread "HTTP-171" [_thread_blocked, id=2011, stack(0x00007f6d06f34000,0x00007f6d07035000)]
  0x00007f6dac146800 JavaThread "HTTP-170" [_thread_blocked, id=2010, stack(0x00007f6d07035000,0x00007f6d07136000)]
  0x00007f6dac144800 JavaThread "HTTP-169" [_thread_blocked, id=2009, stack(0x00007f6d07136000,0x00007f6d07237000)]
  0x00007f6dac143000 JavaThread "HTTP-168" [_thread_blocked, id=2007, stack(0x00007f6d07237000,0x00007f6d07338000)]
  0x00007f6dac141800 JavaThread "HTTP-167" [_thread_blocked, id=2005, stack(0x00007f6d07338000,0x00007f6d07439000)]
  0x00007f6dac13f800 JavaThread "HTTP-166" [_thread_blocked, id=2003, stack(0x00007f6d07439000,0x00007f6d0753a000)]
  0x00007f6dac13d800 JavaThread "HTTP-165" [_thread_blocked, id=1990, stack(0x00007f6d0753a000,0x00007f6d0763b000)]
  0x00007f6dac13b800 JavaThread "HTTP-164" [_thread_blocked, id=1989, stack(0x00007f6d0763b000,0x00007f6d0773c000)]
  0x00007f6dac139800 JavaThread "HTTP-163" [_thread_blocked, id=1988, stack(0x00007f6d0773c000,0x00007f6d0783d000)]
  0x00007f6dac137800 JavaThread "HTTP-162" [_thread_blocked, id=1987, stack(0x00007f6d0783d000,0x00007f6d0793e000)]
  0x00007f6dac135800 JavaThread "HTTP-161" [_thread_blocked, id=1986, stack(0x00007f6d0793e000,0x00007f6d07a3f000)]
  0x00007f6dac134000 JavaThread "HTTP-160" [_thread_blocked, id=1985, stack(0x00007f6d07a3f000,0x00007f6d07b40000)]
  0x00007f6dac132800 JavaThread "HTTP-159" [_thread_blocked, id=1983, stack(0x00007f6d07b40000,0x00007f6d07c41000)]
  0x00007f6dac131000 JavaThread "HTTP-158" [_thread_blocked, id=1982, stack(0x00007f6d07c41000,0x00007f6d07d42000)]
  0x00007f6dac12f800 JavaThread "HTTP-157" [_thread_blocked, id=1981, stack(0x00007f6d07d42000,0x00007f6d07e43000)]
  0x00007f6dac12e000 JavaThread "HTTP-156" [_thread_blocked, id=1790, stack(0x00007f6d07e43000,0x00007f6d07f44000)]
  0x00007f6dac12c800 JavaThread "HTTP-155" [_thread_blocked, id=1789, stack(0x00007f6d07f44000,0x00007f6d08045000)]
  0x00007f6dac12a800 JavaThread "HTTP-154" [_thread_blocked, id=1644, stack(0x00007f6d08045000,0x00007f6d08146000)]
  0x00007f6dac129000 JavaThread "HTTP-153" [_thread_blocked, id=1048, stack(0x00007f6d08146000,0x00007f6d08247000)]
  0x00007f6dac127800 JavaThread "HTTP-152" [_thread_blocked, id=1033, stack(0x00007f6d08247000,0x00007f6d08348000)]
  0x00007f6dac126000 JavaThread "HTTP-151" [_thread_blocked, id=1031, stack(0x00007f6d08348000,0x00007f6d08449000)]
  0x00007f6dac124800 JavaThread "HTTP-150" [_thread_blocked, id=830, stack(0x00007f6d08449000,0x00007f6d0854a000)]
  0x00007f6dac123000 JavaThread "HTTP-149" [_thread_blocked, id=829, stack(0x00007f6d0854a000,0x00007f6d0864b000)]
  0x00007f6dac121800 JavaThread "HTTP-148" [_thread_blocked, id=748, stack(0x00007f6d0864b000,0x00007f6d0874c000)]
  0x00007f6dac120000 JavaThread "HTTP-147" [_thread_blocked, id=666, stack(0x00007f6d0874c000,0x00007f6d0884d000)]
  0x00007f6dac11e800 JavaThread "HTTP-146" [_thread_blocked, id=665, stack(0x00007f6d0884d000,0x00007f6d0894e000)]
  0x00007f6dac11d000 JavaThread "HTTP-145" [_thread_blocked, id=542, stack(0x00007f6d0894e000,0x00007f6d08a4f000)]
  0x00007f6dac11b800 JavaThread "HTTP-144" [_thread_blocked, id=541, stack(0x00007f6d08a4f000,0x00007f6d08b50000)]
  0x00007f6dac11a000 JavaThread "HTTP-143" [_thread_blocked, id=540, stack(0x00007f6d08b50000,0x00007f6d08c51000)]
  0x00007f6dac118000 JavaThread "HTTP-142" [_thread_blocked, id=512, stack(0x00007f6d08c51000,0x00007f6d08d52000)]
  0x00007f6dac116000 JavaThread "HTTP-141" [_thread_blocked, id=511, stack(0x00007f6d08d52000,0x00007f6d08e53000)]
  0x00007f6dac114000 JavaThread "HTTP-140" [_thread_blocked, id=510, stack(0x00007f6d08e53000,0x00007f6d08f54000)]
  0x00007f6dac112000 JavaThread "HTTP-139" [_thread_blocked, id=509, stack(0x00007f6d08f54000,0x00007f6d09055000)]
  0x00007f6dac110000 JavaThread "HTTP-138" [_thread_blocked, id=508, stack(0x00007f6d09055000,0x00007f6d09156000)]
  0x00007f6dac10e000 JavaThread "HTTP-137" [_thread_blocked, id=507, stack(0x00007f6d09156000,0x00007f6d09257000)]
  0x00007f6dac10c800 JavaThread "HTTP-136" [_thread_blocked, id=506, stack(0x00007f6d09257000,0x00007f6d09358000)]
  0x00007f6dac10b000 JavaThread "HTTP-135" [_thread_blocked, id=505, stack(0x00007f6d09358000,0x00007f6d09459000)]
  0x00007f6dac109000 JavaThread "HTTP-134" [_thread_blocked, id=504, stack(0x00007f6d09459000,0x00007f6d0955a000)]
  0x00007f6dac107000 JavaThread "HTTP-133" [_thread_blocked, id=503, stack(0x00007f6d0955a000,0x00007f6d0965b000)]
  0x00007f6dac105000 JavaThread "HTTP-132" [_thread_blocked, id=502, stack(0x00007f6d0965b000,0x00007f6d0975c000)]
  0x00007f6dac103800 JavaThread "HTTP-131" [_thread_blocked, id=501, stack(0x00007f6d0975c000,0x00007f6d0985d000)]
  0x00007f6dac102000 JavaThread "HTTP-130" [_thread_blocked, id=498, stack(0x00007f6d0985d000,0x00007f6d0995e000)]
  0x00007f6dac100800 JavaThread "HTTP-129" [_thread_blocked, id=497, stack(0x00007f6d0995e000,0x00007f6d09a5f000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ff000 JavaThread "HTTP-128" [_thread_blocked, id=343, stack(0x00007f6d09a5f000,0x00007f6d09b60000)]
  0x00007f6dac0fd800 JavaThread "HTTP-127" [_thread_blocked, id=319, stack(0x00007f6d09b60000,0x00007f6d09c61000)]
  0x00007f6dac0fc000 JavaThread "HTTP-126" [_thread_blocked, id=318, stack(0x00007f6d09c61000,0x00007f6d09d62000)]
  0x00007f6dac0fa000 JavaThread "HTTP-125" [_thread_blocked, id=32427, stack(0x00007f6d09d62000,0x00007f6d09e63000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f8000 JavaThread "HTTP-124" [_thread_blocked, id=32426, stack(0x00007f6d09e63000,0x00007f6d09f64000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f6800 JavaThread "HTTP-123" [_thread_blocked, id=32004, stack(0x00007f6d09f64000,0x00007f6d0a065000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f5000 JavaThread "HTTP-122" [_thread_blocked, id=31865, stack(0x00007f6d0a065000,0x00007f6d0a166000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f3800 JavaThread "HTTP-121" [_thread_blocked, id=31864, stack(0x00007f6d0a166000,0x00007f6d0a267000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f2000 JavaThread "HTTP-120" [_thread_blocked, id=31737, stack(0x00007f6d0a267000,0x00007f6d0a368000)]
  0x00007f6dac0f0800 JavaThread "HTTP-119" [_thread_blocked, id=31539, stack(0x00007f6d0a368000,0x00007f6d0a469000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ef000 JavaThread "HTTP-118" [_thread_blocked, id=31538, stack(0x00007f6d0a469000,0x00007f6d0a56a000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ed800 JavaThread "HTTP-117" [_thread_blocked, id=31524, stack(0x00007f6d0a56a000,0x00007f6d0a66b000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ec000 JavaThread "HTTP-116" [_thread_blocked, id=31523, stack(0x00007f6d0a66b000,0x00007f6d0a76c000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ea800 JavaThread "HTTP-115" [_thread_blocked, id=31522, stack(0x00007f6d0a76c000,0x00007f6d0a86d000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e9000 JavaThread "HTTP-114" [_thread_blocked, id=31476, stack(0x00007f6d0a86d000,0x00007f6d0a96e000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e7800 JavaThread "HTTP-113" [_thread_blocked, id=31309, stack(0x00007f6d0a96e000,0x00007f6d0aa6f000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e6000 JavaThread "HTTP-112" [_thread_blocked, id=31279, stack(0x00007f6d0aa6f000,0x00007f6d0ab70000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e4800 JavaThread "HTTP-111" [_thread_blocked, id=31278, stack(0x00007f6d0ab70000,0x00007f6d0ac71000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e2800 JavaThread "HTTP-110" [_thread_blocked, id=31250, stack(0x00007f6d0ac71000,0x00007f6d0ad72000)]
  0x00007f6dac0e1000 JavaThread "HTTP-109" [_thread_blocked, id=31249, stack(0x00007f6d0ad72000,0x00007f6d0ae73000)]
  0x00007f6dac0df800 JavaThread "HTTP-108" [_thread_blocked, id=30912, stack(0x00007f6d0ae73000,0x00007f6d0af74000)]
  0x00007f6dac0de000 JavaThread "HTTP-107" [_thread_blocked, id=30911, stack(0x00007f6d0af74000,0x00007f6d0b075000)]
  0x00007f6dac0dc800 JavaThread "HTTP-106" [_thread_blocked, id=30910, stack(0x00007f6d0b075000,0x00007f6d0b176000)]
  0x00007f6dac0db000 JavaThread "HTTP-105" [_thread_blocked, id=30825, stack(0x00007f6d0b176000,0x00007f6d0b277000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d9000 JavaThread "HTTP-104" [_thread_blocked, id=30624, stack(0x00007f6d0b277000,0x00007f6d0b378000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d7800 JavaThread "HTTP-103" [_thread_blocked, id=30623, stack(0x00007f6d0b378000,0x00007f6d0b479000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d6000 JavaThread "HTTP-102" [_thread_blocked, id=30622, stack(0x00007f6d0b479000,0x00007f6d0b57a000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d4800 JavaThread "HTTP-101" [_thread_blocked, id=30601, stack(0x00007f6d0b57a000,0x00007f6d0b67b000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d3000 JavaThread "HTTP-100" [_thread_blocked, id=30348, stack(0x00007f6d0b67b000,0x00007f6d0b77c000)]
  0x00007f6dac0d1800 JavaThread "HTTP-99" [_thread_blocked, id=30347, stack(0x00007f6d0b77c000,0x00007f6d0b87d000)]
  0x00007f6dac0cf800 JavaThread "HTTP-98" [_thread_blocked, id=30346, stack(0x00007f6d0b87d000,0x00007f6d0b97e000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ce000 JavaThread "HTTP-97" [_thread_blocked, id=30225, stack(0x00007f6d0b97e000,0x00007f6d0ba7f000)]
  0x00007f6dac0cc000 JavaThread "HTTP-96" [_thread_blocked, id=30192, stack(0x00007f6d0ba7f000,0x00007f6d0bb80000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ca000 JavaThread "HTTP-95" [_thread_blocked, id=30191, stack(0x00007f6d0bb80000,0x00007f6d0bc81000)]
  0x00007f6dac0c8000 JavaThread "HTTP-94" [_thread_blocked, id=30190, stack(0x00007f6d0bc81000,0x00007f6d0bd82000)]
  0x00007f6dac0c6800 JavaThread "HTTP-93" [_thread_blocked, id=30187, stack(0x00007f6d0bd82000,0x00007f6d0be83000)]
  0x00007f6dac0c5000 JavaThread "HTTP-92" [_thread_blocked, id=30186, stack(0x00007f6d0be83000,0x00007f6d0bf84000)]
  0x00007f6dac0c3800 JavaThread "HTTP-91" [_thread_blocked, id=30183, stack(0x00007f6d0bf84000,0x00007f6d0c085000)]
  0x00007f6dac0c1800 JavaThread "HTTP-90" [_thread_blocked, id=30182, stack(0x00007f6d0c085000,0x00007f6d0c186000)]
  0x00007f6dac0bf800 JavaThread "HTTP-89" [_thread_blocked, id=30181, stack(0x00007f6d0c186000,0x00007f6d0c287000)]
  0x00007f6dac0bd800 JavaThread "HTTP-88" [_thread_blocked, id=30180, stack(0x00007f6d0c287000,0x00007f6d0c388000)]
  0x00007f6dac0bc000 JavaThread "HTTP-87" [_thread_blocked, id=30179, stack(0x00007f6d0c388000,0x00007f6d0c489000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ba800 JavaThread "HTTP-86" [_thread_blocked, id=30176, stack(0x00007f6d0c489000,0x00007f6d0c58a000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b8800 JavaThread "HTTP-85" [_thread_blocked, id=30175, stack(0x00007f6d0c58a000,0x00007f6d0c68b000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b6800 JavaThread "HTTP-84" [_thread_blocked, id=30173, stack(0x00007f6d0c68b000,0x00007f6d0c78c000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b5000 JavaThread "HTTP-83" [_thread_blocked, id=30170, stack(0x00007f6d0c78c000,0x00007f6d0c88d000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b3000 JavaThread "HTTP-82" [_thread_blocked, id=30169, stack(0x00007f6d0c88d000,0x00007f6d0c98e000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b1800 JavaThread "HTTP-81" [_thread_blocked, id=30168, stack(0x00007f6d0c98e000,0x00007f6d0ca8f000)]
  0x00007f6dac0b0000 JavaThread "HTTP-80" [_thread_blocked, id=30149, stack(0x00007f6d0ca8f000,0x00007f6d0cb90000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ae000 JavaThread "HTTP-79" [_thread_blocked, id=30148, stack(0x00007f6d0cb90000,0x00007f6d0cc91000)]
  0x00007f6dac0ac000 JavaThread "HTTP-78" [_thread_blocked, id=30147, stack(0x00007f6d0cc91000,0x00007f6d0cd92000)]
  0x00007f6dac0aa000 JavaThread "HTTP-77" [_thread_blocked, id=30146, stack(0x00007f6d0cd92000,0x00007f6d0ce93000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a8000 JavaThread "HTTP-76" [_thread_blocked, id=30145, stack(0x00007f6d0ce93000,0x00007f6d0cf94000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a6800 JavaThread "HTTP-75" [_thread_blocked, id=30144, stack(0x00007f6d0cf94000,0x00007f6d0d095000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a5000 JavaThread "HTTP-74" [_thread_blocked, id=30143, stack(0x00007f6d0d095000,0x00007f6d0d196000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a3800 JavaThread "HTTP-73" [_thread_blocked, id=30142, stack(0x00007f6d0d196000,0x00007f6d0d297000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a2000 JavaThread "HTTP-72" [_thread_blocked, id=30141, stack(0x00007f6d0d297000,0x00007f6d0d398000)]
  0x00007f6dac0a0800 JavaThread "HTTP-71" [_thread_blocked, id=30140, stack(0x00007f6d0d398000,0x00007f6d0d499000)]
  0x00007f6dac09f000 JavaThread "HTTP-70" [_thread_blocked, id=30137, stack(0x00007f6d0d499000,0x00007f6d0d59a000)]
  0x00007f6dac09d000 JavaThread "HTTP-69" [_thread_blocked, id=30136, stack(0x00007f6d0d59a000,0x00007f6d0d69b000)]
  0x00007f6dac09b800 JavaThread "HTTP-68" [_thread_blocked, id=30135, stack(0x00007f6d0d69b000,0x00007f6d0d79c000)]
  0x00007f6dac09a000 JavaThread "HTTP-67" [_thread_blocked, id=30134, stack(0x00007f6d0d79c000,0x00007f6d0d89d000)]
  0x00007f6dac098800 JavaThread "HTTP-66" [_thread_blocked, id=30133, stack(0x00007f6d0d89d000,0x00007f6d0d99e000)]
  0x00007f6dac096800 JavaThread "HTTP-65" [_thread_blocked, id=30132, stack(0x00007f6d0d99e000,0x00007f6d0da9f000)]
  0x00007f6dac095000 JavaThread "HTTP-64" [_thread_blocked, id=30131,
```

Comment: Could you post relevant part of your code?

Comment: same error here with jdk7u55 and lucene 4.3 on CentOS.

Comment: The error doesn't tell where caused the Java runtime error, and index code is very simple, I can't see any problem:                                   _searchEngine = SearchEngineFaculty.getSearchEngine(indexDir);
  IndexWriter iw = null;
  try{
   iw =_searchEngine.getWriter(false, true);
   iw.addDocument(doc);
   iw.commit();
  } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
   logger.log(Level.SEVERE, StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(e));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   logger.log(Level.SEVERE, StackTraceUtil.getStackTrace(e));  
  }

Comment: Perhaps /tmp is full?  See [Java SIGBUS - an unclear way of saying /tmp is full](http://efod.se/blog/archive/2011/05/02/java-sigbus).  Looks to be occurring around MMapDirectory access, so seems likely enough.